# Karatzas, Ioannis & Shreve, Steven E. , “Methods of mathematical finance”, Remark 2.2, page 7

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, finance, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

I'm reading the first chapter of Methods of mathematical finance from Karatzas as part of my B.Sc-thesis in mathematics and I try to show the uniqueness of the solution $$G(t) = S_0(t) \int_0^t \frac{1}{S_0(u)} \pi'(u) \mathrm d R(u) $$
 of the following SDE $$ G(0) = 0, $$,
$$\mathrm d G(t) = \frac{G(t)}{S_0(t)}  \mathrm dS_0(t) + \pi'(t) \mathrm d  R(t),$$
if $$ G(t) = \pi_0(t) + \pi'(t) \mathbb{1}$$ for all $t \in [0,T]$. Here is
 R a semimartingale , S has bounded variation on [0,T] and $\pi$ fulfills 
 \begin{align*}
\pi_0 (\cdot) \colon [0,T ] \times \Omega \longrightarrow R , \pi ( \cdot) := ( \pi_1(\cdot) , \ldots, \pi_N( \cdot) \big) \colon [0, T] \times \Omega \longrightarrow R^N  \\
\text{with}
\int_0^T | \pi_0(t) + \pi(t) \mathbb{1} | \big( r(t) \mathrm dt + \mathrm d \tilde{A}(t) \big) < \infty
\text{ almost sure,}    \\
\int_0^T \big| \pi(t) ( b(t) + \delta(t) - r(t) \mathbb{1} \big) \big| \mathrm dt < \infty \text{ a.s.,} \\
 \text{ and }           \int_0^T \| \sigma'(t) \pi (t) \|^2 \mathrm dt < \infty  \text{ a.s. }
\end{align*} 
where $b,\delta,\sigma$ have bounded variation on $[0,T]$.

I could show that G is a solution using Ito' partial integration for stochastic integrals from Philip E. Protter. Stochastic Integration and Differential Equations, II.6, theorem 22, corollary 2 and i used to show the uniqueness of the other stochastic differential equations of this chapter with the following theorem from Philip E. Protter. Stochastic Integration and Differential Equations, V.3, theorem 6

Let $Z_t$  be a semimartingale with $Z_0 = 0$ und let $f \colon R_{>0} \times \Omega \times R \longrightarrow R$ be such that,
$$(i)
\text{for fixed x }  (t, \omega) \longrightarrow f(t, \omega, x)  \text{ caglad is},$$
$$(ii)
\text{for all } (t, \omega) \text{ and a finite random variable } K \text{ the estimation} 
$$$$
|f(t, \omega, x) - f(t, \omega, y)| \leq K(\omega) |x - y|  \text{satisfied is.}
$$
Further let $X_0$ be finite and $\mathcal{F}(0)$-measurable. 
Than the SDE
\begin{align*}
X_t = X_0 + \int_0^t f(s, \cdot, X_{s-}) \mathrm d Z_s  
\end{align*}
has an unique solution which is a semimartingale.

My problem is how to choose $X_t$ and $Z_t$, the term $\pi'(t) \mathrm d  R(t)$ is always a little troublemaker...
I'd like to choose 
$$Z_t:= \int_0^t \frac{1}{S_0(u)} \pi'(u) \mathrm d R(u)$$
but it doesn't work, does it?

Please help, many, many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Note that $S_0(t)$ is the money market value. Then we assume that $d\langle S_0, G\rangle_t = 0$ and that  $d\langle S_0, S_0\rangle_t = 0$. Then,
\begin{align*}
d\left(\frac{G(t)}{S_0(t)}\right) &=\frac{1}{S_0(t)}dG(t) - \frac{G(t)}{S_0^2(t)}dS_0(t)\\
&=\frac{\pi'(t)}{S_0(t)}dR(t).
\end{align*}
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
G(t) = S_0(t)\int_0^t\frac{\pi'(u)}{S_0(u)}dR(u).
\end{align*}

Comment: Hello @Gordon, thanks but as i wrote above that I've already solved the SDE; my question is how to show the uniqueness of the solution? Maybe I don't understand your answer properly but I don't see why the solution should be unique because of this.

Comment: @Probabilitytheoryapprentice: There is no uniqueness mentioned in the book. If you really need, you may need to break down $dR(t)$ using $dW(t)$,

Comment: yes it isn't mentioned in the book, but I believe the solution is unique - I mean if it isn't unique the model of the gain process wouldn't be very useful; but the other SDE of the chapter for example the one with the stock price process can be shown with the theorem i quoted above; I know that in the section of parabolic PDE's you use Gronwall' lemma to show uniquness, that would be another idea, but for me it didn't work - is there something similar in the srochastic calculus?

Comment: By the way $$R(t) := \int_0^t b(u) + \delta(u) - r(u) \mathbb{1} \mathrm du + \int_0^t \sigma(u) \mathrm d W (u)$$ and i don't know how this should help; anyway I upvoted your answer for your effort^^

Comment: @Probabilitytheoryapprentice: The uniqueness for SDE is discussed in [the other book](https://www.amazon.ca/Brownian-Stochastic-Calculus-Ioannis-Karatzas/dp/0387976558) by Karatzas and Shreve.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon, I know and a I already read parts of it; actually Karatzas Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus has a possible answer in 5.2.4 example, page 286; I'll try tomorrow to transform the idea from there